# Custom dialog in angular routing guard

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In angular 2/4 I know that I can write a routing guard to implement the CanActivate routing guard and display a message using standard alerts etc... but I am wondering whether it is possible to write a component with its own HTML/CSS/TS so that I can get the dialogs to fit in the theme of the application or even pull the text to display from a backend service.

I have tried to look around and have not been able to find any examples of how to write a routing guard with a dialog with its own HTML/CSS/TS files which can be displayed.

Does any one have an small examples that I can look at to modify further?  Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create/append an element to the body tag from the route itself using JS. You can style the element either using the JS below, or by adding a class to `this.el` and using CSS in your main stylesheet.

```
import { Injectable }               from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate , Router}      from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class LoginGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        public ngRouter: Router
    ){}

    private el

    async canActivate() {
        try {
            this.showLoader()
            await yourAsyncScript()    
            return true  
        } catch (err) {
            this.ngRouter.navigate(['/'])
            return false
        } finally {
            this.removeLoader()
        }      
    }


    showLoader(){
        this.el = document.createElement('div')
        this.el.innerHTML = `
            <div>Loading...</div>
        `
        this.el.style.cssText = `
            user-select: none;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 50000;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            color: black;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        `
        document.body.appendChild(this.el)
    }

    removeLoader(){
        if (this.el) {
            document.body.removeChild(this.el)   
            this.el = null
        }
    }

}
```